# Converting IPTables rules to Firewalld

Tags: networking, iptables, firewalld

I'm working on setting up Cuckoo Sandbox and I have several IPTables rules that need to be converted to Firewalld rules.

Here's the reference page for the Cuckoo Sandbox install guide: http://docs.cuckoosandbox.org/en/latest/installation/guest/network/#virtual-networking

The 3 lines that I need to convert from IPTables format are (Subnet removed):

`iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i vboxnet0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE`

I've made an attempt to convert the rules and implement them using firewall-cmd, and here are the three updated rules that I came up with:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i vboxnet0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter POSTROUTING 0 -t nat -j MASQUERADE`

However, when I attempt to add one of the above rules using `sudo firewall-cmd` I get a response that says:

`wrong priority
usage: --direct --add-rule { ipv4 | ipv6 | eb } <table> <chain> <priority> <args>`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have just copied and pasted your `iptables` arguments to the back of an `firewall-cmd` command: that will not work.  The error message is telling you that it is not finding what it expects after 'ipv4': table, chain, priority and args.  You need something like:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

You can add MASQUERADE in a couple of ways:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-masquerade

firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Here is a good reference for getting started with firewalld: https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-firewalld/